# How can one see the percentage of one's answers that were posted on one's own questions, network-wide?

Tags: support, self-answer

Is there a way to see the percentage of one's answers that were posted on one's own questions, network-wide?

Comment: I couldn't find any example in data explorer using keywords, and [if there is one it's not correctly tagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-answer+data-explorer).